# How to extract the text of a .ppt file with tika?

Tags: java, apache-tika, text-extraction

I have extracted the text of a .pdf file with tika using `AutoDetectParser` class. but when I use the same code for extracting the text of a .ppt file, it throws an exception.  How to do it? 
thanks

EDIT:
The code that I used is:

```
File file = new File("1.ppt");
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
Parser autoDetectParser = new AutoDetectParser();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
ContentHandler handler = new WriteOutContentHandler(writer);
autoDetectParser.parse(input, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
```

and the exception was:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SMALLER_BIG_BLOCK_SIZE_DETAILS
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:93)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:190)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:184)
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.POIFSContainerDetector.getTopLevelNames(POIFSContainerDetector.java:371)
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.POIFSContainerDetector.detect(POIFSContainerDetector.java:165)
at org.apache.tika.detect.CompositeDetector.detect(CompositeDetector.java:61)
at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:113)
at ppt.PPTParserTest.test3(PPTParserTest.java:52)
```

I found out that the problem caused by some extra `jars` that have been in my `classpath`.

Comment: I have used the `parse()` method of `AutoDetectParser` class like this parameters: autoDetectParser.parse(inputStream, contentHandler, metadata);

Comment: And what was the exception?

Comment: Could you share what extra jars were conflicting to enlighten others with this problem?

Comment: @computermacgyver This problem had take placed two month ago, but I think one of the(or maybe both of) these two libraries had caused the problem: 1.poi-3.1-FINAL.jar and 2.poi-scratchpad-3.1-FINAL.jar

Comment: Thanks, @user2041057, for the reply. I reached the same conclusion and removing both jars from my classpath solved the issue. Best wishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exception can happen if you have two different versions of POI in your runtime classpath. 
In newer versions of POI, `NPOIFSFileSystem` references `POIFSConstants.SMALLER_BIG_BLOCK_SIZE_DETAILS`. This constant does not exist in older versions of POI.

I ran into this exception with `tika-app-1.4.jar` (which bundles POI 3.9) and `poi-3.0.2-FINAL-20080204.jar` in my classpath.

Answer (score -2):

you can change your method `WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)`
instead of `WorkbookFactory.create(File)`, this can solve you problem. good luck !